# A free software CV/résumé parser

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, pdf

I'm seeking a software solution to extract data from résumé/CV in various format (PDF, Microsoft Word, etc.).

What I need is :

1. extracting name, surname, email, phone numbers, segmented postal address (street, zipcode, etc.) into a exploitable structured output
2. a free software solution
3. extracting other typical résumé entries (previous jobs title, etc)
4. a solution which directly integrate the previous results into [OpenERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odoo) (note that OpenERP is now known as [odoo](https://www.odoo.com/)).

Ideally it would integrate seamlessly with [OpenERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odoo), but any solution that would provide a key/value output would be enough as I can develop the integration glue myself. It just should let me obtain results on a Linux server, so a Linux compatible software would be better but even a web service with a reasonable response time for an interactive usage may be fine.

From my own research [Open Applicant](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20091006152306344/OpenApplicant.html) could have been a good candidate as it provided "resume parsing" and was free software. But unfortunately it looks like it disappeared from the web.

Non-free softwares that may do the job include [DaXtra Parser](http://www.daxtra.com/products/daxtraparser/), ResumeGrabber, [Rchilli Resume Parser](https://www.rchilli.com/), Automated Hr Software Resume Parser.

Comment: [OrangeHRM](http://www.orangehrm.com/Features.html#Recruitment) announces that it integrates "_Shortlist using resumes parsing to read resumes and keywords_", but I don't know yet [whether it's  a native solution or if it relies on some SaaS](http://forum.orangehrm.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=13885&sid=17e0386c5dd0f0759d159be17fb2783b).

Comment: Did you ever come around this? Did you find a solution? If yes, would you post an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't found any satisfying answer at the time, and I don't plan to make further investigation on this topic.

Comment: Although the OpenApplicant code is gone from Sourceforge http://sourceforge.net/projects/openapplicant/files/, it seems to have been retained here: http://en.pianshen.com/1360840/

Comment: I would suggest that you post that as an answer. Well done for finding it. As far as I can see on the Way back Machine, that page never had a download link https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20091006152306344/OpenApplicant.html

Answer (score 4):

Given that the tone of your question suggests some programming experience I would suggest that this could probably be achieved in [python](http://www.python.org) by:

1. Converting each CV to a common format, such as markdown or plain text:

   - Word .docx Use the built in [docx module](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
   - Word .doc  Call [antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) to convert to plain text
   - Pdf, (**not** scanned documents), [pdfminer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer/)
2. **Either**: select relevant data using a set of python regular expressions using [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)/[regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) *this will probably give you the quickest results but possible not the most comprehensive* **or**:
3. Parse and analyse using the nltk - this is possibly the more powerful solution but will take a lot of time and effort to implement.

   - extracting name, surname, email, phone numbers, segmented postal address (street, zipcode, etc.) into a exploitable structured output - **Yes** A good set of regular expressions should be sufficient for this.
   - Free - **Yes** *apart from development costs*
   - extracting other typical résumé entries - *Depends on the effort that you put in and will probably require the nltk solution*.
   - Integrate with OpenERP - since you can output in whatever format you need I would say yes or you could use an [OpenERP Client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openerp-client-lib/).
   - Run on a Linux server - **definitely**.

Answer (score 2):

I came across one more resume parsing company [www.candidatezap.com](http://www.candidatezap.com) 
they claim able to upload resumes to many ATS / CRM without a coding / programming and no need to integration.

Comment: Hello! Could you please expand your answer to make it self-containing? Try to structure it so that it answer the 4 points in the OP question!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a free Resume / CV parsing api service you can use, pretty simple to integrate with your applications or websites. Has some sample .net code integration on [the website](https://www.bighelpdesk.com/cvparseapi.aspx)

Comment: Looks like that link is now dead :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a free resume parser, check out https://affinda.com/resume-parser/

The output is in XLS, JSON and XML formats. This solution was built using the latest advancements in Natural Language Processing, to ensure it can handle the broadest set of resume formats.

You would need to develop the described integration yourself, and it should be straightforward given the output can be in a JSON file.

Fields include name, location, phone, email, websites, work experience (job, employer, location, dates), education (institution, degree, location, dates), skills and more.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Sounds an interesting solution but not free as in free software. Rather the opposite actually, as it seems a cloud only only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Our [CV parsing software](https://www.rchilli.com/solutions) helps you to extract details from resumes. Usually, it supports all formats of resumes/CVs.

Comment: Could you give some e details.  For instance, what is the output format? XML? Can It write straight to my database? Also, what's the pricing (not necessary to answer the question, but nice to know). I guess it supports Linux as the OP asked. Windows too?

Comment: Also, is there an example output file anywhere on your website, so that we can see exactly what it looks like?

Comment: The output is available in XML and JSON formats. It will help to store straight in your database, CRM or ATS. To serve better please provide your details here. (https://www.rchilli.com/contacts).

Comment: If you had posted details here, you could have helped many people and gotten many enquirers. As it is, I would like such a service, but am not going to enquire if you don't give any detail here